# UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, keyboard

I got error just at the first run after I built my app. according to the error info, sees like I give two different height constraint, but I don't.

error information

```
2022-08-26 12:32:15.618688-0300 LzchEx[7002:191006] Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 6453: (null)
2022-08-26 12:32:15.741349-0300 LzchEx[7002:190797] [Warning] WARNING: A Gesture recognizer (<UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0x7fc232507e80; state = Possible; view = <UIButton 0x7fc232011b30>; target= <(action=LongPressDelete:, target=<LzchEx.KeyboardViewController 0x7fc233817400>)>; numberOfTapsRequired = 0; minimumPressDuration = 0.5>) was setup in a storyboard/xib to be added to more than one view (-><UIView: 0x7fc23250e220; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000085ed30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000655e60>>) at a time, this was never allowed, and is now enforced. Beginning with iOS 9.0 it will be put in the first view it is loaded into.
2022-08-26 12:32:15.803627-0300 LzchEx[7002:190797] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000256a4e0 UIView:0x7fc23250e220.height == 250   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000257f9d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fc23250e220.height == 926   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000257f9d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fc23250e220.height == 926   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-08-26 12:32:15.804392-0300 LzchEx[7002:190797] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
```

my code

```
    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view as Any,
                                               attribute: .height,
                                               relatedBy: .equal,
                                               toItem: nil,
                                               attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                               multiplier: 0.0,
                                               constant: 250) // Set custom height here
    self.view.addConstraint(constraint)
```

maybe problem happened here, according to the error info

```
@IBAction func LongPressDelete(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTimer(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    } else if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .cancelled {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        }
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450)
}
//DeleteBUtton (secondary keyboard) long pressed
@IBAction func LongPressDelete2(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

          if sender.state == .began {
              timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTimer(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
          } else if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .cancelled {
              timer?.invalidate()
              timer = nil
              }
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450)
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to set the height of the "root view" of a view controller... which is something you almost certainly **do not** want to do. If that's not the case, you need to provide some more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: why not use the interface builder?

Comment: i am trying to set a new view for landscape